# Angularjs controller ng-app not working

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am noticing before I created this controller that ng-app="myApp" broke the data binding with an input field and the template I had before.
Now i have a controller with route provider and the ng-view in the index.html doesn't work at all (blank page).
Am I missing something?

```
    <!doctype index.html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js">             </script>
     <script src="js/lib/angualar.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/lib/angualar-route.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/lib/angualar-animate.min.js"></script>  
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <nav class="cf" ng-include="'views/nav.html'"></nav>
  </header>
  <div class="page">
  <main class="cf" ng-view></main>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>

<!doctype js/app.js>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'appControllers']);

var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
      when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
    })
}]);

<!doctype views/nav.html>
<div class="table">
  <ul>
    <li class="branding"><a ng-href="#/">angularData</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/meetings">Meetings</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/register">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So few inputs watching your code:

1. Do a CTRL+Shift+I and open console tab in your browser to view the error reported, as your code has too many logical error and needs to be debugged.
2. `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'appControllers']);`

In app.js appControllers is used as a dependency but its never mentioned in your html as `data-ng-controller="appController"`

Hence remove appControllers dependency.

3. With context of your code

`var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);` is redundant too and will have errors as there are no appControllers defined in html

Here is the working code of, have kept it simple:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js">             </script>
     <script    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
       <script    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   <script>
   angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
      when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
    })
}]);
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <div class="table">
  <ul>
    <li class="branding"><a ng-href="#/">angularData</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/meetings">Meetings</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/register">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </header>
  <div class="page">
  <main class="cf" ng-view></main>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that code. It did work but I have to add that this is not my code but a tutorial example from a instruction website. I did have one thing wrong. My includes were missing a directory: <script src="js/lib/**angular**/angualar-route.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also, thanks for Ctrl-Shift-I. Once there I noticed that my folders for min.js were not showing up.
in the source tree I had localhost:8000/js/app.js. nothing else. But i had physical folder of js/lib/angular with all the min.js files in it. Not sure why it couldn't see these with the correct path of src="js/lib/angular

Comment: Same for my views/login.html and nav.html. Neither show in that localhost:8000 tree. 
I'm using Git bash with a gulp script by the way to launch this. 
Once I changed my src include scripts to your cdnjs.cloudflare.com..... it worked with my code.

Comment: Also, that code you said was redundant and to remove, was supposed to be a namespace. not sure of the theory but that is what it said. Sorry still learning and this stuff is so archaic to me.

Answer (score -1):

what is `<!doctype index.html>` if it is part of your code then remove all `doctype` from your code. your working code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RG1fXn6B1vn4r46JT8MB)

and also you have not included your `views/login.html` code in your app.

Comment: I'm not sure what that was, it was from a tutorial, sorry , I just used it as a comment header for each section. I shouldn't have done it, made it confusing I know, I removed it.